# ASP.NET Core - When is IServiceProvider disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am facing problem with disposed IServiceProvider object in ASP.NET Core 3.1 application:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
```

I am capturing `IServiceProvider` object inside `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class and using it in `BackgroundService`. Most of the time this works fine but occasionally `ObjectDisposedException` is thrown. I can understand that `IServiceProvider` in `ConfigureServices` is not indented to be used like that. So I am wondering:

- When is `Dispose/DisposeAsync` called on `IServiceProvider`? What is `ServiceProvider` lifecycle?
- What is the correct way of referencing `IServiceProvider` in ASP.NET Core in BackgroundService? Should I use `IServiceScopeFactory` and create new scope there?

Comment: Maybe this discussion on github will be useful for you https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/31478

Comment: Your `static void Main()` method should dispose the `IHost` / `IWebHost`.

Comment: You can inject IServiceProvider to other services through constructor. No need to capture it in Startup.

Comment: This is still an issue, and I cant find any decent answers. If I read on learn.microsoft.com, there are numerous examples of injecting IServiceProvider in the constructor, saving that as a field in the class, and then using that IServiceProvider to create a scope, when needed. However, when I do exactly that, I get that the IServiceProvider is Disposed.

Answer (score 5):

Use `IServiceScopeFactory` which is singletone by design for safe and controlled resolving of other services. It is a factory for creating instances of `IServiceScope`, with the only `IServiceScope CreateScope()` method to create services within a scope. Once this is disposed, any scoped services that have been resolved from the `IServiceScope.ServiceProvider` will also be disposed.

Real life example:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult FooJob([FromServices] IServiceScopeFactory resolver, JobContract job)
{
    //long running task
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    using var scope = resolver.CreateScope();
                    var svcProvider = scope.ServiceProvider; //Scopped lifetime
                    var mediator = svcProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
                    var request = RunFooJob.Command.Create(job);
                    return await mediator.Send(request);
                });
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK);            
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#request-services) has put me on the following track.

In **ASP.NET Core**, you should retrieve the IServiceProvider via the HttpContext. The HttpContext is available directly in a controller.

```
var a = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<...>();
```

In other classes, you can get it via an IHttpContextAcessor, which you have to add as a service beforehand.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

.

```
public class YourClass : IYourClass
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public YourClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) =>
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        IServiceProvider? _serviceProvider = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.RequestServices;
        var newService = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<...>(...);

        // ...
    }
}
```

As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#httpcontext-access-from-a-background-thread), however, you should note that HttpContext is not thread-safe.

And additionally you can test if an IServiceProvider is already disposed. (I also didn't understand why or under what circumstances this happens.) (Works with ASP.NET Core 7)

```
private static bool isServiceProviderDisposed(IServiceProvider sp)
    => (bool)(sp.GetType()?.GetField("_disposed", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)?.GetValue(sp) ?? true);
```